# Fairly basic mod Rewrite issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

My site filters everything through the index.php script, and in reading the docs for mod_rewrite, it seems pretty darn easy, but I'm a bit stuck.  I figured I would begin a page at a time to see if i could get it to work, and got stuck pretty quickly.

I have user profiles, the longform of which is basically:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?content=profile&id=2172
```

So i added one Rewrite rule to my .htaccess file that sits in the root folder:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ index.php?content=profile&id=$1
```

The idea is now to be able to enter `mysite.com/profile/2172`

The redirect does bring up the proper page, but what is happening is that every CSS file, image, etc is getting /profile/ added in the middle, which is of course not where the image and CSS files are located.  I use relative pathnames in the code so an example of an image in the code might be:  `images/userimage.jpg`

What is happening is that the relative link shown above gets turned into:

```
mysite.com/profile/images/username.jpg
```

To me that makes no sense as the image path does not match the rewrite pattern (`/profile/*`), so why does the bogus path add `/profile/` to all of my internal links?

I tried adding `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f` to the htaccess just before the rewriterule just to see what happened, no change.

Sorry if this is a simple and basic question, but can anyone with real mod rewrite expertise give me some pointers so that I can make this simple case work and bring up the page with the proper references in my code to my included css and image files?  I didn't use any flags to the Rewriterule since I only have that one line after the engine is turned on (and the followsymlink line is there as well).

Answer (score 0):

> To me that makes no sense as the image path does not match the rewrite pattern (/profile/*), so why does the bogus path add /profile/ to all of my internal links?

Your images are relative to the page being served, which does have `/profile/` e.g. `mysite.com/profile/2172`. You may want to consider changing your image/css links to be absolute from root i.e. `/images/imag.jpg`.

If that is not possible you could use another rewrite to correct the issue (just for this case, not really recommended in general) as below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#rewrite to remove profile for jpg, css etc, must go above existing rule below
RewriteRule ^profile/(.+\.(jpg|css|js|png))$ $1 [L,NC]

#existing rule
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ index.php?content=profile&id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Remember that when your HTML does a relative href, it's the user's _browser_ that interprets this by adding the host and directory path, and this is why it is requesting `/profile/images/username.jpg` not `/images/username.jpg`, so what Ulrich is suggesting is either (a) modify your code to emit absolute references (i.e. with the leading **/**) _OR_ (b) add the above rule to strip out the extraneous `/profile`.

Comment: The real reason I use all relative profiles is that I have several copies of my site, the "live" site and the "dev" site, so using absolute profiles would not allow me to test new code in the dev site before it goes live as it would be accessing stuff at the live site with absolute paths.  I would think that would be an issue with any real dynamic site where you make new modules and features and test them before going live to the members

Comment: Ulrich said "You may want to consider changing your image/css links to be absolute from root i.e. /images/imag.jpg."  Does that mean that if I just add a slash to the beginning of my src="" path (/images/image.jpg instead of simply images/image.jpg) that will turn it into a path from the root and not use the prefix?

Comment: @BenCahan yes, if it is absolute from the root dir i.e. `/images...` then your images etc should not be affected by the `/profile` in the url

Comment: Ulrich, yeah, that worked fine, just adding the slash at the front was the real solution, getting it out of the relative path.  Thanks guys, problem solved, now I just have  to go through the code and add a slash in front of all the relative paths.  then I can modify one page at a time to shorten my URL's and make it search engine friendly, which has been the problem all along

Comment: @BenCahan please show your gratitude, by accepting this answer. You can do this by clicking the check-mark to the left of it. Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow.