# How can I use mod_rewrite to remove the query string from my URL?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am new at mod_rewrite and need some help if is possible.

this is my old url

```
www.mysite.com/web/page.php?c=categoryname
```

I need to change it at:

```
www.mysite.com/web/page/categoryname.html
```

I am using this code but it doesn't work:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /web/  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?c=$1 [L]
```

How can I fix the above code to correctly rewrite my URLs?
EDIT:

Thanks to Ulrich Palha
i manage to redirect the html files, but css,js etc are not redirect and the website looks rly bad, this is the code i am using now, till i will get the one who will redirect css too

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /web/

    #redirect www.mysite.com/web/page.php?c=categoryname to
    #www.mysite.com/web/page/categoryname.html
    #prevent internal redirect
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)c=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(page)\.php$ $1/%2.html? [NC,L,R=301]

    #rewrite www.mysite.com/web/page/categoryname.html to
    #www.mysite.com/web/page.php?c=categoryname 
    RewriteRule ^(page)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ $1.php?c=$2 [L,NC]
```

BUMP ANY HELP PLEASE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the web directory of your site, replacing the rules you have above.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/

#do not process css/js etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|jpg|png) [NC] 
#alternatively you could skip all existing files. Comment previous line and uncomment next to do so
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#redirect www.mysite.com/web/page.php?c=categoryname to
#www.mysite.com/web/page/categoryname.html
#prevent internal redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)c=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(page)\.php$ $1/%2.html? [NC,L,R=301]

#rewrite www.mysite.com/web/page/categoryname.html to
#www.mysite.com/web/page.php?c=categoryname 
RewriteRule ^(page)/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ $1.php?c=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have pasted it on the httacess file and when i click on the old link, it redirects me at :
http://mysite.com/web/page/categoryname.html?c=categoryname, and it give 404 error

Comment: after your edit now it redirects on the patch i need, but i get NOT FOUND ERROR

Comment: @JoinOG I tested locally and it works. Do you have any other rules in this .htaccess file or any rules in the root directory?

Comment: i am sorry for the delay of my answer, no i have nothing else on the .httaccess i have copy pasted it.

Comment: i just get 404 error. the redirect its ok, but why i got NOT FOUND ERROR. also i try it on localhost and i got 404 error  again. ..

Comment: @JoinOG enable the Rewrite Log via `RewriteLog "/path-to-your-log/rewrite.log"' and set the `RewriteLogLevel 9`. These 2 lines can be added to your virtual host (on your localhost apache) to see why the Rule is not matching

Comment: i have deleted the root directory .httaccess file, and now it redirects without 404 error, but i think css is not redirect and java script too. how can i redirect them ? thnx

Comment: Ulrich Palha thnx for the help man, as i said, now the problem is only css and jss files. and the web looks rly bad without them.

Comment: @JoinOG What is url for CSS/js in your html? If it is a relative path in you .html see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098418/fairly-basic-mod-rewrite-issue/ for solution

Answer (score 1):

Your regex in the rule is wrong — you are missing `/page`, adding an optional final slash that you shouldn't be, and forgetting to remove the `.html` part. Also your `RewriteBase` shouldn't have a final slash and your rule shouldn't have a leading slash.

It total, it should be this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /web  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)\.html$ page.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have tryed it , also want to say that .httacces file is on WEB directory .. should i wait to see it working ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: i want to change the way that my links looks, when i click on www.mysite.com/web/page.php?c=categoryname it dont redirect on the new link, and if i write the new link manually on the browser, i got 404 error